# EF doesn't assign new ID to model

Tags: .net, entity-framework, orm, mapping

I have an app with Entities, where every user has an Inventory object

```
public class BattlegroundUser : IdentityUser
    {
        [Required]
        public Inventory Inventory { get; set; } = new Inventory();
    }
```

And every Inventory has a Cards list which contains Card models

```
public class Inventory
    {
        public Inventory()
        {
        }

        public Inventory(string inventoryId, List<Card> cards, string inventoryOfId)
        {
            InventoryId = inventoryId;
            Cards = cards;
            InventoryOfId = inventoryOfId;
        }

        [Key]
        public string InventoryId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public List<Card> Cards { get; set; } = new List<Card>();

        [Required]
        [ForeignKey("InventoryOf")]
        public string InventoryOfId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public BattlegroundUser InventoryOf { get; set; }
    }
```

and here is the Card model

```
public class Card
    {
        public Card(string cardId, string name, int health, int attack, int defend, string inInventoryId)
        {
            CardId = cardId;
            Name = name;
            Health = health;
            Attack = attack;
            Defend = defend;
            InInventoryId = inInventoryId;
        }

        [Key]
        public string CardId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int Health { get; set; } = 100;

        [Required]
        public int Attack { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int Defend { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [ForeignKey("InInventory")]
        public string InInventoryId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public Inventory InInventory { get; set; }
    }
```

I am not sure if this setup is correct, but check out my DbContext

```
public class BattlegroundContext : IdentityDbContext<BattlegroundUser>
    {
        public override DbSet<BattlegroundUser> Users { get; set; }

        public DbSet<Card> Cards { get; set; }

        public DbSet<Inventory> Inventories { get; set; }

        public BattlegroundContext(DbContextOptions<BattlegroundContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);

            builder.Entity<BattlegroundUser>()
                .HasOne(inv => inv.Inventory);

            builder.Entity<BattlegroundUser>()
                .HasKey(c => c.Id);

            builder.Entity<Inventory>()
                .HasMany(i => i.Cards)
                .WithOne(c => c.InInventory);

            builder.Entity<Inventory>()
                .HasOne(c => c.InventoryOf);

            builder.Entity<Inventory>()
                .HasKey(c => c.InventoryId);

            builder.Entity<Card>()
                .HasOne(inv => inv.InInventory);

            builder.Entity<Card>()
                .HasKey(c => c.CardId);

            List<Card> DefaultCards = new List<Card>();

            Card card1 = new Card("-1", "Bonnie", 1000, 1000, 1000, "1");
            Card card2 = new Card("-2", "Bab", 100, 100, 100, "1");
            Card card3 = new Card("-3", "Tom", 10, 10, 10, "1");

            DefaultCards.Add(card1);
            DefaultCards.Add(card2);
            DefaultCards.Add(card3);

            builder.Entity<Card>()
                .HasData(DefaultCards);
            // Customize the ASP.NET Identity model and override the defaults if needed.
            // For example, you can rename the ASP.NET Identity table names and more.
            // Add your customizations after calling base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        }
    }
```

As you can see I try to seed some cards into the database.
Add-migration and update-database runs fine then when I try to create a new account I get this error message in Register.cshtml.cs

```
                var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, Input.Password);
```

Unable to track an entity of type 'Inventory' because its primary key property 'InventoryId' is null.

I am not sure why it doesn't assign a new Id to the Inventory

EDIT: I am using EF Core 5

EDIT2:

Here is the whole action:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
        {
            returnUrl ??= Url.Content("~/");
            ExternalLogins = (await _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList();
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var user = new BattlegroundUser { UserName = Input.Email, Email = Input.Email };
                var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, Input.Password);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    _logger.LogInformation("User created a new account with password.");

                    var code = await _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);
                    code = WebEncoders.Base64UrlEncode(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(code));
                    var callbackUrl = Url.Page(
                        "/Account/ConfirmEmail",
                        pageHandler: null,
                        values: new { area = "Identity", userId = user.Id, code = code, returnUrl = returnUrl },
                        protocol: Request.Scheme);

                    await _emailSender.SendEmailAsync(Input.Email, "Confirm your email",
                        $"Please confirm your account by <a href='{HtmlEncoder.Default.Encode(callbackUrl)}'>clicking here</a>.");

                    if (_userManager.Options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount)
                    {
                        return RedirectToPage("RegisterConfirmation", new { email = Input.Email, returnUrl = returnUrl });
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
                        return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
                    }
                }
                foreach (var error in result.Errors)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, error.Description);
                }
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return Page();
        }
```

Comment: Can you precise the EF version? EF Core 5?

Comment: Yes it's EF Core 5 @Vernou

Comment: Can you show the `BattlegroundUser` class?

Comment: It's the first example in my post @Vernou

Comment: var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, Input.Password);  can you show the whole action?

Comment: @Sergey I updated the question, see Edit 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the user is added in the context, all foreign entities are added in the context. In you case, the user and him inventory are added in the context.

In the `BattlegroundUser`class, the `Inventory` property is initialized with default constructor :

```cs
public Inventory Inventory { get; set; } = new Inventory();
```

But the default constructor do nothing and the id isn't initialized :

```cs
public class Inventory
{
    public Inventory()
    { }

    [Key]
    public string InventoryId { get; set; }
}
```

The not initialized id is null, then when it add in the context you get this error. You can reproduce by simply adding an inventory in the context :

```cs
using var context = new BattlegroundContext(options);
context.Add(new Inventory());
//System.InvalidOperationException:
//'Unable to track an entity of type 'Inventory' because its primary key property 'InventoryId' is null.'
```

The solution is to correctly initialized the inventory. This inventory require a id and a USER :

```
public class BattlegroundUser : IdentityUser
{
    public BattlegroundUser()
    {
        Inventory = new Inventory() { 
            InventoryId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
            InventoryOf = this
        };
    }

    [Required]
    public Inventory Inventory { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I get this error now, at the same line Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Inventories' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

Comment: `string` id property isn't identity column by default (cf . [Generated Values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/generated-properties?tabs=data-annotations#primary-keys). Can you check if the column `InventoryId` in the table `Inventories` is identity in the database?

Comment: It's nvarchar(450)

Comment: But it's identity and increment? For SQL Server you can check with the query : `sp_help Inventories`. You will see a dataset with columns `Increment` and `Identity`.